# Usage of "only" in "Private cloud operates like a public cloud only"

Tags: word-usage, word-request

**[Source](http://marketrealist.com/2014/07/private-cloud-security-solution-organizations/)**

> Private cloud operates like a public cloud **only**, but the resources are
>   operated exclusively for a single organization.

The message to be conveyed is:

> Private cloud operates **just like** a public cloud except that the resources are operated exclusively for a single organization.

The usage of "only" in first sentence seems wrong to me. In my opinion, the word "only" makes it sound more like:

> Private cloud operates like a public cloud only and not like any other
>   cloud.

Am I correct about the interpretation of the sentence or is it grammatically correct? If it's wrong, what would be the correct one-word-replacement of "only"?

Comment: Maybe it's **Indian English** in your first quote. See [related discussion on ELU](http://english.stackexchange.com/q/333310/50044)

Comment: @NVZ: I'm not sure. I read it on a website which is a '.com' website. I would have confirmed it to be Indian if it were a '.in' site. Btw, is it acceptable in Indian English? What would be the correct word in British and American English?

Comment: Yea, acceptable and frequently used in Indian English. Do check out the link in my first comment. :)

Comment: NVZ - Perhaps "Anne Shields" is a _nom de plume,_ then? @7_R3X - given the construction of the sentence, your _just like_ is acceptable if a little informal. You might write instead:  _Private cloud operates exactly as a public cloud does, except that the resources are operated exclusively for a single organization._

Comment: @P.E.Dant : Thanks for the edit and for the comment. What I want to know is if there's a single word for it in Br/Am English.

Comment: _Exactly_ is close, as is _indeed._ It's actually superfluous in most cases, though, it seems to me, as in the sentence you cited. It conveys no information. (By the way, a .com TLD doesn't exclude the possibility that a site is of Indian origin, nor does a .in TLD ensure that it is.)

Comment: *operates like a public cloud, but/except . . .* You can use one word there. (Like)

Comment: Domain name is registered in Canada.

Comment: @user3169 I am irresistibly reminded of Peter Lorre's line from *Beat the Devil*: "Many Germans in Chile have come to be called O’Hara."

Comment: @user3169 No; although the _registrar_ is a Canadian company, their resellers operate all over the world. The address given in _whois_ is that of the Canadian company which hides the identity of Marketrealist's true _registrant._ The .com _registry_ is still controlled by a U.S. entity. None of these tell us where the domain is registered, i.e. where Marketrealist.com conducts its business.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your example sentence

> Private cloud operates like a public cloud **only**, but the resources are operated exclusively for a single organisation.

there may be a typo since the sentence works without "only" and also without "but", or transposed

> Private cloud operates like a public cloud **only** the resources are operated ...
>   Private cloud operates like a public cloud **but** the resources are operated ...
>   Private cloud operates like a public cloud **but only** the resources are operated ...

In the section of the article for your example sentence the author is comparing and contrasting public and private clouds and the wording of any of the three sentences could be used to convey this thought.

Comment: I doubt a typo, @Peter. Other pieces by "Anne Shields" contain usages which might be Indian English. Also, the comma after _only_ makes a transposition with _but_ extremely unlikely.

Comment: I supposed she might be saying that a Private cloud operates exactly the same as a Public cloud, that there isn't any additional functionality, as in "exactly the same, no more and no less", and that a difference is which side of the Firewall the cloud is on, but the reading becomes a bit torturous.

Comment: @Peter It's most probably Indian English. I see such sentences in India very often.